# Equation concerning distance to nearest integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

First of all, my question arises from http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa67/aa6745.pdf page 350 which is page 2 in the pdf.

Let $s$ be an integer $\geq5$ then I want to show that $$2\max\left(\left\lVert\sqrt{2s}\right\rVert,\,\left\lVert\sqrt{2s}-1/2\right\rVert\right)=1/2+\left\lVert\sqrt{8s}-1/2\right\rVert$$ where $\lVert\,.\rVert$ denotes the distance to the nearest integer.

Note, that $\sqrt{8s}=2\sqrt{2s}$ which allows to prove a more general form for $x\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ instead $$2\max\left(\left\lVert x\right\rVert,\,\left\lVert x-1/2\right\rVert\right)=1/2+\left\lVert 2x-1/2\right\rVert$$
This can be done by considering $4$ cases.

We define for simplicity $A(x):=2\max\left(\left\lVert x\right\rVert,\,\left\lVert x-1/2\right\rVert\right)$ and $B(x):=1/2+\left\lVert 2x-1/2\right\rVert$

Let $0 \leq x-\lfloor x\rfloor < 1/4$ then $$A(x)=1-2\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)=B(x)$$
Let $1/4 \leq x-\lfloor x\rfloor < 1/2$ then $$A(x)=2\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)=B(x)$$
Let $1/2 \leq x-\lfloor x\rfloor < 3/4$ then $$A(x)=2-2\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)=B(x)$$
Let $3/4 \leq x-\lfloor x\rfloor < 1$ then $$A(x)=2\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)-1=B(x)$$

I don't like that proof, because I considered $4$ cases.

My question is: Do you see a nicer proof? Since the paper says that all of this is "easy to see" I'm wondering whether I'm missing something that would allow a proof with a different, more direct argument?